# C++ class member with same name as in base class

Tags: c++, gcc

How does the this pointer behaves when used inside a base class method:

```
class Base{
public:
   int a;
   Base() : a(5) {}
   void func(){
       std::cout << " value is : " << this->a << std::endl;
   }
};

class Derived : public Base{
private:
   int a;
public:
   Derived() : a(1){}
   void func1(){
       std::cout << " value is : " << this->a << std::endl;
   }
};

int main(){
   Derived d;
   d.func();
   d.func1();
}
```

the output of the code is :

value is : 5

value is : 1

As i am using the same object to call both the functions. So will the value of this pointer differ in methods for base and derived class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this->a` is equivalent to `a` in that context, so it has nothing to do with the base pointer.

The member `a` is resolved statically, and the derived class hides the base class member, since they're both named `a`.

To check the `this` pointer itself, you can print it directly:

```
std::cout << this;
```

It will be the same for both objects.

The main thing to take from this is that `Base::a` and `Derived::a` are different. Try the following in `Derived`:

```
void func1(){
    std::cout << "derived value is : " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "   base value is : " << Base::a << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: this pointer is actually the address of the created object. and derived class object has values for both the variables (Base and derived). so why does this->a behaves differently in both the methods ?

Answer (score 0):

**`this` pointer will always point to current object in which it exists.**

When `func` is called, Base class is used and base class field is printed. but,

When `func1` is called, Derived class is used and it's field is printed.

---

Try commenting this line `Derived() : a(1){}` and you'll get more clarity.

Comment: It points to the object, not the class. You can't point to a class.

Comment: Yes, but to make OP understand, i wrote that way. and in brackets gave more clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do `this->Base::a` to access Base's `a`. Else you always access `Derived::a`.